# phptelnet vs phpseclib

Tags: php, phpseclib

I am trying to connect a unix server from php and execute .exe (C language). Earlier I used phptelnet for this purpose, but now I need to shift to phpseclib due to security issues. I had 100% success rate when I use phptelnet. I could run some of the external programs like 'C' programs with arguments as input in php script. In phptelnet I use

```
$telnet->DoCommand('cd public_html');
$telnet->DoCommand('cd abc');
$telnet->DoCommand('demo.exe');
$telnet->DoCommand("$inputs", $result);
echo $result;
```

This works perfect. But now I am using phpseclib. I could connect to the unix server via ssh and execute programs in which the inputs are hard coded in the program. I am using

```
echo $ssh->exec('./demo.exe');
```

Now the problem is how to provide inputs to the program. How can I use exec() to accept arguments as inputs. For example, demo.exe is a program to add two numbers. so can I say

```
 echo $ssh->exec("./demo.exe, '10 20'");
```

Also how can I use exec() to execute multiple lnes of code in a single execution. I am a bit confused. Any inputs on this are greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you attempted to simply add the arguements to the first parameter, i.e. echo $ssh->exec("./demo.exe 10 20"); ?

Comment: Hey Seidr, Thanks for the comment. Yes. I did add the arguments as you have mentioned. The script became unresponsive when I tried that way.

Answer (score 0):

Where you have multiple options to commands you'd use:

```
 $ssh->exec("./demo.exe '10' '20'");
```

Leave out the comma, and enclose individual parameters each. Or convert a list with `$opts = implode(" ", array_map("escapeshellarg", $opts))`.

If you are using a SSH1 connection, you can only execute one command at a time. If you are connecting to a Windows server (which this looks like), then you can't have two commands on a line.

Only for a BSD/Linux server you could use:

```
 $ssh->exec("cmd1 ; cmd2");
```

Comment: Thanks mario for the suggestions. My script doesnt respond when I use $ssh->exec("./demo.exe '10' '20'"); I will give a try with implode() and let you know. BTW I could run multiple commands as suggested by you  $ssh->exec("./demo.exe ; ./hello.exe");. I have to look for options for accepting arguments. 
Thanks for the reply..

Comment: Implode() won't help then. If this is a Win server (??), then single quotes might not work at all. Try double quotes or skip the escaping, if so.

Comment: Hey mario. I tried using double quotes and escaping, doesnt work either.. Thanks for your comments.